# How to judge whether a point is inside a closed surface

Tags: algorithms

Give the point cloud of a closed surface(triangle mesh models), how to judge whether a point is inside the closed surface? As we know, in 2-D situation, there are some algorithms to do this.

Comment: And there are the same for 3D, one easy is to calculate normals (or if the mesh serves any purpose, the normals are already calculated) and check on which side the point lies. Do you have some requirements or you could add some details?

Comment: My model are obj, the normals are provided, how to judge a point whether in the model by normals?  Can you explain the detail? Thank you!

Comment: The easy way is to make scanline / ray test - try to hit some triangles, and the normal gives you sign to determine on which side you are. If mesh is very big and there are several triangles in hit test - like with counting on 2d you have to remember how many hits there were. Some kind of localization is needed to perform many tests - it would consume to much time checking all the triangles from the mesh. The comment you gave on SO about reducing dimensions - as I checked several tests are needed because we do not know where this projection should be made. Do you have "capsules"?